# What does it mean if my puppy acts different when my mom comes home?

Tags: dogs

For example, his behavior changes he cries a lot at the gate for no reason and acts bad But if there not there he's good. They go to the river pretty much every weekend when it's nice out and when they come home he acts like this, I've had him for almost 3 months in a few days. Can anyone explain why he does this or if we should be concerned?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little difficult to understand the scenario you're describing. If he acts out when *they're there* it might be his way of trying to get *their* attention because he really enjoys it when they take him to the river. Do you go to the river with them too?

Ask your vet or other dog owners for advice about training and raising pups. Your vet could probably recommend someone local who could help you train him.

You might also want to get him more exercise when your mom isn't around. He'll respond well to regular and focused play time, exercise and any training that you give him. Is he trained on a leash yet? Does he know "sit"? "Paw" (to hold up his paw when he's sitting to "shake hands")? Does he know "down" to lie down? Does he know "off" to get off people and stuff? Keeping a regular routine of feeding, doing his business, exercise, training and such will do a lot to keep his temper even. Stick with it now and for the next year and a half and you'll have a lifetime of happy puppy :)

Answer (score 0):

Behavioral issues for any pet are training issues. We need to work on training our pet to act the way we like it to as it has no way to identify what is good or bad.

Consistency is the first and foremost answer to training. No matter what training you give you must always remain consistent. Pets do not understand abstracts like this is "OK" sometimes, but other times not.

What I feel is likely the scenario is that you treat your pet one way when you mom is around, and another when she isn't. You may give in to your pet's crying and bad behavior, but ignored it early on. The best way to train your dog to stop the bad behavior is to remove the reward, in this case your mom, when it starts acting up. After several times of losing the reward from the poor behavior, your dog will start to understand that the unwanted behavior does not gain any positive reaction.

Keep in mind punishing the dog is **NOT** the answer. Giving your dog negative attention not only makes the animal fear and distrust you, but it also reinforces a behavior.